# Unable to ping redis server port 6379 from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Redis in Ubuntu distro in Windows using WSL and I am trying to connect to the server from Windows command prompt.

When I ping the local IP (172.29.0.1) of Ubuntu, I get the ping result but when I ping the same IP with the port number (172.29.0.1:6379) then I am getting this error message.

```
Ping request could not find host 172.29.0.1:6379. Please check the name and try again.
```

I have started the redis server on Ubuntu using
`sudo service redis-server start`

And when I ping the server on Ubuntu's terminal, I am getting the response back.

```
:~$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
```

I have also tried executing `sudo ufw allow 6379` command to expose 6379 port but it has not helped.

How can I connect to the Redis Server that is running on Ubuntu from my Windows command prompt or any other application running in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt **Redis** responds to regular `ping` requests which use [ICMP packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) .

If you want to check your **Redis** server is up, install the `redis-cli` tools on Windows and send a Redis-style *"ping"* with:

```
redis-cli -h 172.29.0.1 PING
```

Comment: If I try to invoke this then I am getting this error

"Could not connect to Redis at 172.29.0.1:6379: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: Removing the host parameter helped. 
Redis in linux is directly listening at 127.0.0.1:6379. There was no need to specify the local IP of the system.

Comment: Oh, ok. I don't use Windows and am unfamiliar with how WSL works. I was envisaging the Ubuntu appeared more like a different machine with a different IP address. Glad you got it working.